# Alert sum result based on row and class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to sum the text value inside table. here is what i try

```js
$(document).on("change", ".kd1", function() {
      var sum = 0;
      $('.kd1').each(function() {
       sum += Number($( this ).closest('.kd1').val());
      })
      alert(sum);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

For now, i'm able to alert it. **But** the result is the total of each `tr` so i want to Separate the result each row. how can i achieve that ? thanks in advance

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please provide an example of input and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem very user-friendly to present sums in an `alert`. Instead you could add another column to the table, and display the sums there.

To calculate the sums per row, just add an outer loop on the rows, and calculate the sum for a row inside that loop. I would suggest using `reduce` for getting the sum, but that is just a detail. See it work in this snippet:

```js
$(document).on("change", ".kd1", function() {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        $('.sum', this).text(
            $('.kd1', this).get().reduce(function(sum, elem) {
               return sum + +$(elem).val();
            }, 0)
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
  <td class="sum"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="kd1"></td>
  <td class="sum"></td>
 </tr>     
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Well alert just for the test. This part `$('.sum', this).text` new for me. New question =  new knowledge. Thanks

Comment: Make sure to understand the second argument to `$()`: it specifies under which elements the selector (first argument) should be applied -- it restricts the search. That element can be a DOM element, like here, or a jQuery expression. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Answer (score 0):

You can put every result into an array where every index is the index of the row

```
var currentRow=$(this).closest('tr');
var index=$('table tr').index(currentRow);
sum[index]=0;
$(currentRow).find('.kd1').each(function() {
    sum[index] += Number($( this ).val());
 })
```

Comment: hmmm. how to alert it ?